# Xcode C++ autocomplete is fast in main function but slow in other places

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, ide

I am writing C++ on OS X, and the best IDE I've found yet is Xcode. But the automatic code completion is weird. The suggestion will appear only after two or three seconds. To be specific, while I type

```
str
```

the list that contains suggestions including `string` and other identifiers won't appear until I stop typing and wait for 2 or 3 seconds. So basically, the auto completion is UNUSABLE!!

Strangely though, the auto code completion is super fast in the `main()` function.

Is there any explanation to such strange behavior of the automatic code completion in Xcode when writing C++?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd describe its performance as terribly unreliable.  Sometimes it feels responsive, on other occasions it's like it's gone for a cigarette outside and forgotten entirely about my autocomplete needs...